# Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type bitmap scan0

Tags: c#, image

i defined my own 24 bit data type like this

```
class _24bit{
        public byte[] _value = new byte[3]; 
   }
```

i have data in binary in a _24bit data array

```
 _24bit  []data = new _24bit
```

i declared my bitmap as

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(columns / 3, rows, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

but when i declare this to get a row in the bitmap

```
_24bit *row = (_24bit *)bmd.Scan0 + (j * bmd.Stride);
```

i get this compile error

Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('mynamespace._24bit')

How can i proceed with my own 24bit data type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't declare pointers to managed reference types (and your _24bit class is managed reference type). Even if you declare `_24bit` as a `struct` (making it a value type), it still contains a reference to a byte array (not byte array itself, only a reference, which makes size of this struct larger than 24 bits). You can declare you array as `fixed` and `unsafe` to fix that. You also might need to specify `StructLayout` attribute:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, Size=3)]
struct _24bpp
{
    public unsafe fixed byte _value[3];
}
```

Note, that you can only access content of this struct in `unsafe` context. Or drop array declaration at all:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, Size=3)]
struct _24bpp
{
    public byte B;
    public byte G;
    public byte R;
}
```

Alternatively, you can recreate bitmap in terms of your data structures and copy data from unmanaged memory to your data structures. Something like

```
public static _24bit[][] GetBitmapPixelsFrom24bpp(BitmapData data)
{
    if(data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

    var bitmapRows = new _24bit[rows][];
    for(int row = 0; row < data.Height; ++r)
    {
        bitmapRows[row] = new _24bit[data.Width];
        for(int pixel = 0; pixel < data.Width; ++pixel)
        {
            byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(data.Scan0, data.Stride * row + pixel * 3 + 0);
            byte g = Marshal.ReadByte(data.Scan0, data.Stride * row + pixel * 3 + 1);
            byte r = Marshal.ReadByte(data.Scan0, data.Stride * row + pixel * 3 + 2);
            var bitmapPixel = new _24bit();
            bitmapPixel._value[0] = b;
            bitmapPixel._value[1] = g;
            bitmapPixel._value[2] = r;
            bitmapRows[row][pixel] = bitmapPixel;
        }
    }
    return bitmapRows;
}
```

Comment: are sure the order is b g r and not R G B ?

Comment: yes, `Format24bppRgb` is confusing, because it is really BGR byte order.

Comment: i wanted a row pointer so that i could fill it with data, can i do that with your function?

Comment: no, this function only reads data into managed memory and does not provide raw pointers. you need to change your `_24bit` class according to one of suggestions to do that. this function shows a concept how you could still work with the bitmap without changing your data type.

Answer (score 0):

`_24bit` is a managed reference type, getting a pointer to it would essentially be getting a pointer to a reference to some non-constant location on the heap, which isn't what you want.

Declare `_24bit` as a `struct` instead of a `class` and you'll be able to use pointers with it as long as it only contains unmanaged types. It's explained in more detail in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx).

```
struct _24bit
{
    public byte r, g, b;

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0: return r;
        case 1: return g;
        case 2: return b;
        default: //throw exception or return 0 or something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did as you said but now i get this error message "cannot have instance field initializers in structs"

Comment: C# structs act a bit differently than C/C++ structs, C# structs have a default constructor that initializes everything to it's default value and all constructors must inherit from that. You're also not allowed to initialize variables like you do in `_24bit`. So you have two options, either add a constructor `public _24bit(byte unused) : this() { _value = new byte[3]; }` or, a better solution, replace `_value` with `byte r, g, b;`. If you still want to use indexers with #2, use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx

Comment: It seems I also completely forgot about the fixed array... option #3, you can replace `public byte _value = new byte[3];` with `public fixed byte _value[3];` I also updated my answer to use my second option.

Answer (score 0):

You cant initialize structure like Robert G. wrote.

Put your structure into class that initializes structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your class to

```
class bmp24bit()
{
    public byte[] _value = new byte[3]; 
}
```